# Unable to bind socket with my local address

Tags: java, sockets, binding

I have a `javax.net.SSLSocket` wich I initialise doing the following:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, hostPort, InetAddress.getByName(localAddress), localPort);
sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

and my client connects to the server no problem. 
When I close the connection `sslSocket.close()` and I try to initialise a new socket using the same local address and the same host address but different host port and different local port the connection is refused and I get `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket2 = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, hostPort2, InetAddress.getByName(localAddress), localPort2);
sslSocket2.startHandshake();
```

What is weird is that when I try to reinitialise the new socket without binding it to my local address and port then it works fine:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket2 = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(host, port2);
```

anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So after loads of digging I found what prevents this exception from happening. Straight after the socket is initialised you need to add the line `sslSocket.setSoLinger(true, 0);`. 
How SoLinger works is explained here http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=33897 . 
Well I am still not sure if that is the right way to fix it but I hope that it helps people with similar problems.